# Поймать процесс что грузит диск в windows

Tags: windows, hdd, мониторинг

При выключенном экране (простое) windows какой-то процесс начинает сильно грузить диски. Как можно отловить что это за процесс? Диспетчер ресурсов, Process Monitor не подходят, потому что диск нагружается при простое системы. Если включен экран - загрузка сражу же прекращается. На вирусы проверял cureIt от dr. web.

Comment: Win7 и старше(про висту не уверен) - в фоновом режиме, при простое системы индексируют файлы\делают дефрагментацию, и множество других операций которые могу нагружать дисковую подсистему. По описанному вами поведению подходят обе указанные, а так же исправление бэдов самим винчестером

Comment: В том же taskmgr существует графа прочитано/записано/прочее - т.е. даже если операция не выполняется - можно выяснить какой процесс выполнял i/o операцию. Активируйте столбцы - и думаю, что получится выяснить.

Comment: Может отловить события через Spy++?

Answer (score 1):

Считаю свой ответ не полным, но в качестве подсказки, думаю,  подойдет для русской версии Windows.

1. Открыть "Системный монитор" Windows.
2. Открыть "Производительность". Выбрать раздел "Группы сборщиков данных", затем подраздел "Сеансы отслеживания событий".

3.1. Создать вручную **группу сборщиков данных** с произвольным именем "**123**".

3.2. В **поставщики** добавить: *Microsoft-Kernel-Disk*, *Microsoft-Kernel-File*

3.3. Указать **каталог**, где будет сохранен журнал.

3.4. Запустить группу сборщиков данных "**123**".

3.5. Все вышеописанное в пунктах 3. можно сделать с помощью консольной утилиты **logman.exe**

3.6. По истечении времени, достаточного для сохранения в журнал сведений об активности дисковой подсистемы, нужно остановить созданную группу сборщиков: либо из оснастки системного монитора, либо командой: **logman stop 123 -ets**

4. Далее нужно открыть сохраненный журнал в формате **.etl**, а затем провести анализ активности.